# Getting warning "Failed to create agent because there is no valid Navmesh" using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, navmesh

I'm using procedural mesh geometry and I've set Navigation Static 'On' in the Navigation Window. I've also set the mesh generator to 'Static' in the inspector. I also baked my enemy's agent, but it is still throwing the warning "Failed to create agent because there is no valid NavAgent" that is most likely causing the error: "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh. That error is happening every frame. What can I do to create a better NavMesh?

Links:

Procedural Mesh Geometry

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html

Nav Mesh

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-NavigationSystem.html

Comment: Please add the warning you are getting to the post and explain what errors you are encountering